How to pass an object from Layout to page in Blazor .Net 8
I have a Blazor .Net 8 WebApp application with perpage rendering. My layout page is in the server app and is just a plain SSR with no interactivity.
I have a scoped service where I set properties from the OnInitializedAsync method in the layout. My page is in the client app and has InteractiveAuto with prerendering = false. In the client page the scoped service does not have any properties set.
In .Net 6 or 7 Server app the values can be retrieved from the page and works perfectly. Apparently scoped services do not hold values across render modes. I cannot use Singleton because these values are user specific.
I have tried CascadingValues, but these cannot cross render modes either. I also tried static properties that also didn't work. I cannot use localstorage because localstorage cannot be used in OnInitializedAsync. I don't want to use OnAfterRenderAsync because these values are needed on every page and I would never be able to use OnInitializedAsync on the pages.
Does anyone know a way to pass the data? I can't imagine I am the only one in need of this.

You could try use cookie to store value which can be access in any render mode. Such as following:
First install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 2.2.2 in the client project.
Then add following script at the bottom of "App.razor".
<script>
    function getCookie(key) {
        const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
        const parts = value.split(`; ${key}=`);
        if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
    }

    function setCookie(key, value) {
        document.cookie = `${key}=${value}`;
    }
</script>

Then in any page you could use httpContext or jsinterop to operate the cookie.
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<button @onclick="test">test</button>

@code {

    [CascadingParameter]
    HttpContext? httpContext { get; set; }

    private async Task test()
    {
        if (httpContext != null)   //when SSR httpContext is not null.
        {
            //get cookie
            var cookieValue = httpContext.Request.Cookies["key1"];
            //set cookie
            httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("key1","value1");
        }
        else   // when InterActive Server/WASM , httpContext is null. So use javascript.
        {
            //get cookkie
            var cookieValue =await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("getCookie","key1");
            //set cookie
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("setCookie", "key1", "value1");
        }
    }
}


The problem with that is you can't get cookie with with jsinterop in OnitializedAsync; not available until OnAfterRenderAsync.

I changed the architecture and did it a completely different way. Thanks for the suggestion though.
